# branch is not a function in react using yup schemas with when and then

Tags: reactjs, yup

In react using yup , i have created this schema

```
const RefereeFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  mobile: Yup.string().matches(APP_CONFIG.REGEX_PHONE, 'Invalid Mobile').required('Mobile is required'),
  relationship: Yup.string().required('Relationship is required'),
  isContacted: Yup.boolean().required('Contacted status is required'),
  contactDate: Yup.date().when('isContacted', {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.date().required('Contact date is required'),
    otherwise: Yup.date(),
  }),
});
```

ui gets rendered but when in input box i type anything or try changing the values using dropdown it shows

```
branch is not a function
TypeError: branch is not a function
    at Condition.fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_formik_dist_formik_esm_js-node_modules_yup_index_esm_js.chunk.js:2510:51)
    at Condition.resolve (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_formik_dist_formik_esm_js-node_modules_yup_index_esm_js.chunk.js:2523:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors-node_modules_formik_dist_formik_esm_js-node_modules_yup_index_esm_js.chunk.js:2919:71
```

anything wrong in this?

**Update1**

now i tried with this

```
const RefereeFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  mobile: Yup.string().matches(APP_CONFIG.REGEX_PHONE, 'Invalid Mobile').required('Mobile is required'),
  relationship: Yup.string().required('Relationship is required'),
  isContacted: Yup.boolean().required('Contacted status is required'),
  contactDate: Yup.date()
    .when('isContacted', {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.date().required('Contact date is required'),
    })
```

now same error is thrown when i click on checkbox only for isContacted field

and by default checkbox is not cheked and contact date is not shown but in this case i am not able to click the save button

here is the jsx

```
const RefereeFormSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required('Name is required'),
  mobile: Yup.string().matches(APP_CONFIG.REGEX_PHONE, 'Invalid Mobile').required('Mobile is required'),
  relationship: Yup.string().required('Relationship is required'),
  isContacted: Yup.boolean().required('Contacted status is required'),
  contactDate: Yup.date()
    .when('isContacted', {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.date().required('Contact date is required'),
    })
  // .when('isContacted', {
  //   is: false,
  //   then: Yup.date(),
  // }),
});

const RefereeForm = ({ referee, enquiryId, onSave, onClose }) => {
  console.log("RefereeForm ~ enquiryId:", enquiryId);
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(!referee?.id);

  const formikRefereeForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      id: referee?.id || 0,
      enquiryId: enquiryId,
      name: referee?.name || '',
      mobile: referee?.mobile || '',
      relationship: referee?.relationship || '',
      isContacted: referee?.isContacted || false,
      contactDate: referee?.contactDate || null,
    },
    validationSchema: RefereeFormSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      await onSave(values);
      setEditMode(false);
    },
  });

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setEditMode(true);
  };

  return (
    <FormikProvider value={formikRefereeForm}>
      <Form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={formikRefereeForm.handleSubmit}>
        <Card sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Grid container rowSpacing={3} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item>
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
                    Referee: {referee?.name || 'New Referee'}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                name="name"
                label="Name"
                autoComplete="off"
                error={formikRefereeForm.touched.name && Boolean(formikRefereeForm.errors.name)}
                helperText={formikRefereeForm.touched.name && formikRefereeForm.errors.name}
                onChange={formikRefereeForm.handleChange}
                value={formikRefereeForm.values.name}
                fullWidth
                disabled={!editMode}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                name="mobile"
                label="Mobile"
                autoComplete="off"
                error={formikRefereeForm.touched.mobile && Boolean(formikRefereeForm.errors.mobile)}
                helperText={formikRefereeForm.touched.mobile && formikRefereeForm.errors.mobile}
                onChange={formikRefereeForm.handleChange}
                value={formikRefereeForm.values.mobile}
                fullWidth
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
              />
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <TextField
                required
                name="relationship"
                label="Relationship"
                select
                autoComplete="off"
                error={formikRefereeForm.touched.relationship && Boolean(formikRefereeForm.errors.relationship)}
                helperText={formikRefereeForm.touched.relationship && formikRefereeForm.errors.relationship}
                onChange={formikRefereeForm.handleChange}
                value={formikRefereeForm.values.relationship}
                fullWidth
                disabled={!editMode}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
              >
                {/* {Object.keys(Relationship).map((relationship, index) => (
                  <MenuItem key={index} value={relationship}>
                    {relationship}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))} */}
                <MenuItem value={Relationship.FamilyMember}>{Relationship.FamilyMember}</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={Relationship.Friend}>{Relationship.Friend}</MenuItem>

              </TextField>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <FormControlLabel
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    name="isContacted"
                    color="primary"
                    checked={formikRefereeForm.values.isContacted}
                    onChange={formikRefereeForm.handleChange}
                    disabled={!editMode}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                  />
                }
                label="Is Contacted"
              />
              {formikRefereeForm.errors.isContacted && formikRefereeForm.touched.isContacted && (
                <FormHelperText error>{formikRefereeForm.errors.isContacted}</FormHelperText>
              )}
            </Grid>

            {formikRefereeForm.values.isContacted && (
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  name="contactDate"
                  label="Contact Date"
                  type="date"
                  onChange={formikRefereeForm.handleChange}
                  value={formikRefereeForm.values.contactDate}
                  fullWidth
                  disabled={!editMode}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
            )}

            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={onClose} sx={{ mr: 2 }}>
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                {editMode ? (
                  <>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="inherit"
                      disabled={!editMode}>
                      Save
                    </Button>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <Button variant="contained" color="inherit" onClick={handleEdit}>
                    Edit
                  </Button>
                )}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Card>
      </Form>
    </FormikProvider>
  );
};

RefereeForm.propTypes = {
  referee: RefereePropType,
  enquiryId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onSave: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default RefereeForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then` and `otherwise` fields should be [functions](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/v1.3.3/src/Condition.ts#L11).

```js
  contactDate: Yup.date()
    .when('isContacted', {
      is: true,
      then: (s) => s.required('Contact date is required'),
    })
```

Comment: can we mark * on label based on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have applied functions for both my then and otherwise still i am getting the branch is not a function error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).